# Firebase query is not working in Admin if I use same query in Angular it is working expected. Why this diffrence?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

When I using the below code in the front end angular it's working as expected. But when I am trying to run the same in admin firebase function is not working.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const consumptions = await db
      .collection("consumptions")
      .where("created_at", ">=", "2021-03-31T18:30:00.000Z")
      .where("in_house_sku", "==", "S_52165")
      .get();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working" ? Is there any error?

Comment: I can tell you, I use the *exact same "wrapper" code* in both client and admin environments for Firestore (you can see my wrapper library on npm @leaddreamer/firebase-wrapper).